# Binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{b} \pmod{n}$, $n > b$, $n$ odd, $n,b$ positive integers, AKS test

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, primality-test

I am looking at the values of Binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{b}  \pmod{n}$, where $n > b$, $n$ odd, and $n,b$ positive integers. I am planning to use the results in an implementation in python of the AKS primality test.

Examples of binimial coeffs mod $n$:

1. $b=3, n=5$, $$\binom{5}{3}  \pmod{5} \cong 0$$
2. $b=10, n=15$, $$\binom{15}{10}  \pmod{15} \cong 3$$

Since it is mentioned in comments, Lucas's theorem is for $n$ prime, but I am considering odd $n$.

I have found that there are several patterns, that I think may depend on the factorisation of $b$

Examples of patterns found (using assumptions stated):

1. For $b=6$:

$\binom{n}{6} \pmod{n} \cong \frac{n}{3}$ when $n \pmod{3} \cong 0$ and $n \pmod{9} \cong 0$

$\binom{n}{6} \pmod{n} \cong \frac{2n}{3}$ when $n \pmod{3} \cong 0$ and $n \pmod{9} \cong 6$

$\binom{n}{6} \pmod{n} \cong 0$ when $n \pmod{3}$ is not cong to $0$

2. For $b=7$:

$\binom{n}{7} \pmod{n} = \frac{n}{7}$ when $n \pmod{7} \cong 0$

$\binom{n}{7} \pmod{n} = 0$ when $n \pmod{7} $ not cong to $0$

3. For $b=8$:

$\binom{n}{8} \pmod{n} \cong 0$

Questions:

1. What is the relationship between $\binom{n}{b} \pmod{n}$ and $b$ for odd $n$?
2. Seeking reference requests.

Comment: Not following.  $\binom 42=6$, yes?

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  As I say, unless I am misunderstanding (always possible), $\binom 42$ is already a counterexample as is $\binom 22=1$ come to that...so what are you asking?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking,  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu question updated, and added 2 examples. Please review

Comment: $\binom {10}8=45$ which is not $0\pmod {10}$.

Comment: @lulu Corrected example & updated question

Comment: I don't see a question at all here now.  You say 'I have found there are several patterns' but the text has only two random examples of binomial coefficients without any indication as to what patterns they're supposed to represent.

Comment: Whatever pattern you're seeing is likely to be related to [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: I have updated the question again. Lucas's theorem is for $n$ prime, but I am only considering odd $n$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki notification that question has been updated

Comment: @micah notification that question has been updated

Comment: @lulu notification that question has been updated

Comment: @rtybase notification that question has been updated

Comment: First example I tried was $b=6,n=8$.  According to you that should be $0\pmod 8$ but $\binom 86=28$.    Please take the time to ask a sensible question.

Comment: @lulu I define $n$ as odd in the assumption in question

Comment: Fair enough, my example is not a counterexample.

Comment: The gcd of $\binom{n}{k}$ and $n$ is always greater than $1$ except for the trivial end counter-examples. I'm not aware of any more specific relationship.

Comment: "I am planning to use the results in an implementation in python of the AKS primality test."  Do be aware that the Numberphile video is quite misleading, and this is not the AKS test.

Comment: @danaj I haven't watched the Numberphile video. Please post the link

Comment: @unseen_rider https://youtu.be/HvMSRWTE2mI, which makes it sound like this is AKS.  Some sites like [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes) started propogating it.  On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) this is eq 1 in the concepts, which explains that it was known long ago and is terribly inefficient.  It is Lemma 2.1 in the [AKS paper](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf), which points out it is exponential time (in size of n).  AKS is all about improving that result.

Answer (score 2):

As a consequence of theorem 4 in

1. Andrew D. Loveless: A Congruence for Products of Binomial Coefﬁcients modulo a Composite, in: [*INTEGERS* 7](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol7.html) (A44 10 Jan 2007)

we have $\binom{n}{b}\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ if (but not only if) $\gcd(n,b)=1$. The other theorems and corollaries in the paper may be of interest to you as well.